# Hadoop - Reducer class in java

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, for-loop

I am developing a Hadoop project in java. I want to find the customers with max consumption in  a certain day. I have managed to find the customers in the date I want, but I am facing a problem in my Reducer class. Here is the code:

**Mapper Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class alicanteMapperC extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    String Customer = new String();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date t = new Date();
    IntWritable Consumption = new IntWritable();
    int counter = 0;

    //new vars
    int max=0;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Date d2 = null;
        try {
             d2 = ft.parse("2013-07-01 01:00:00");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (counter > 0) {

            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                Customer = itr.nextToken();
                try {
                    t = ft.parse(itr.nextToken());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Consumption.set(Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken()));
            }

            if (t.compareTo(d2) == 0) {
                context.write(new Text(Customer), Consumption);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Reducer class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class alicanteReducerC extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    IntWritable maximum = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int max = 0;

        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            if (val.get() > max) {
                max = val.get();
            }
        }

        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            if (val.get() == max) {
                context.write(key, val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why the reducer won't write to the output file? In other words, why doesn't the second for works?

**EDIT**
In my mapper class I find the Customers in a specific date and thus the consumption of them and I pass these values in the reducer class.

In the reducer class I want to find the max consumption and the customer associated to this consumption.

Comment: I am not sure why you need second for loop in your reducer. Writing context.write(key, val); after the first for loop would have same effect. However from your problem description I am getting an impression that you want to collect all the keys that have max value. If this understanding is right then I do not think your reducer is doing that.

Comment: @Amit Check my edit. In the reducer class, I want to calculate the max consumption and then the customers having this max consumption. I don't see any other way , than two for loops.

Comment: In My Opinion, you need 2 map-reduce jobs chained together to do this. First Job should find out the MAX consumption and then the second Map-Reduce job ( It could be only mapper I think) to filter out the customers who have this MAX consumption. Two for loops will not work because you are getting all the consumption values for same key which I understand is your customer.

Comment: @Amit Yeah, you understand right; key is the customer. So, you suggest to create two mappers and other two reducers? To chain them, I just have to call each one after the previous one in my driver class? But how do I know  that the 1st reducer will pass the values to the 2nd mapper?

Comment: cool, however please note it is a chain of Two Map-Reduce jobs (which is different than chain of two mappers and two reducers). I think there is a way to pass on value obtained from first map-reduce job to the next, but I have never done this myself. One other way to pass value is store that value in a file in HDFS and make your second map-reduce job read that as an input in addition to your customer-consumption records. Also explore the possibility of use of Pig or Cascading APIs which would ease your job.

Comment: Are you sure your mapper outputs anything? I can't see how it can, due to the `counter` variable which will be zero every time you process a line of your input.

Comment: @BinaryNerd It does write to the output file.

Comment: Thats at the reduce stage, but if your mapper isnt writing anything out then you need to look at that first. What do the jobs counters tell you about the number of records emitted from the mapper.

Comment: @BinaryNerd For some reason, in my mapper class, if I remove the if statement mapper doesn't output, as you correctly pointed, anything. Do you have any idea why this is happening?